# UE4 C++ Getting a reference to HUDClass after it has been initialized

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4, unreal-development-kit

In my Game Mode Base class I create an object that is assigned to HUDClass. The HUD works properly but then I cannot seem to access any of its member functions that require sending code back. I have tried absolutely everything at this point and am completely stuck. It seems whatever I do the pointer to the object seems to become NULL. I am using UE4.25.3.

```
void AGameModeBase::InitGame() {
       HUDClass = AKeyHUD::StaticClass();
}
```

Here are some things I've tried, which all don't work except to access its members which don't require internal variables. I included the most promising two. No matter what I try the statement `if (defaultHUD)` always returns false and if I try to access it it crashes UE4.

```
defaultHUD = HUDClass->GetClass();

defaultHUD = Cast<AKeyHUD>(HUDClass);
```

If anyone can help me out that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what class is the bottom code snippet in? the game mode class?

Comment: The bottom code is also in Game Mode Base, although I figured out a solution to the problem which I will be posting now, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out a solution to get a reference to both any actor object and the HUD from within the Game Mode Base class, this works in Unreal Engine 4.25 using C++. After initializing the `HUDClass` and the `DefaultPawnClass` using a place that they will be initialized (I personally put them in the Game Mode Base Constructor):

```
HUDClass = AMyHUD::StaticClass();
DefaultPawnClass = APlayerPawn::StaticClass();
```

Then to get a reference to the HUD, the following code works assuming your HUD Class name is `AMyHUD` and is callable from many places including `StartPlay()`:

```
defaultHUD = Cast<AMyHUD>(UGameplayStatics::GetPlayerController(this,0)->GetHUD());
```

What this does is get the HUD that is attached to the first players controller, although changing the number changes which Player Controller to get a reference from.

Now to get a reference to any actor of a class the following code works, also placeable in `StartPlay()`:

```
TArray<AActor*> FoundPawns;
UGameplayStatics::GetAllActorsOfClass(GetWorld(), APlayerPawn::StaticClass(), FoundPawns);

defaultPawn = Cast<APlayerPawn>(FoundPawns[0]);
```

Both the `defaultPawn` and the `defaultHUD` are then callable and useable in a straightforward manner such as:

`defaultPawn->YourActorsFunction();`

I hope that helps save people time and is useful.